# Is Gmail API supports Google wallet as upload parameter?

Tags: gmail, android-pay, gmail-api

As we all know that we can now transfer money through `Gmail` to `Google wallet`but I want to make this process as automated (as per the requirement of the project).

Everything is fine! But I can't see any `upload_type` parameter for attaching `wallet-Money`. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately the Gmail API doesn't support attaching a wallet payment.